# Search in html using PHP

Tags: php, html

I would like to find elements or to get image links in HTML, see example HTML below, i tried the PHP method to get the image link, but i dont know what is wrong with my code can someone help me please with example, thanks and thanks to Stackoverflow

example html:

```
<div class="items">
<div class='photoBorder'>        
<a class="box-thumb" data-fancybox-group="thumb" href="//example.com/Resize134_700_1000.jpg"><img title="test" width="220" height="165" style="height:165px; width: 220px;" onerror="$(this).parent().parent().remove();" itemprop="image" src="//example.com/Resize134_700_1000.jpg" alt="test" />
</a>        
</div>
</div>
```

My code :

```
foreach($html->find('div.items div.photoBorder a.box-thumb') as $imageLink)
        {
            $images[] = $imageLink->href;
        }
```

Comment: do you want to get using `jQuery` or php?

Comment: Why did you tag the question PHP if you want to use jQuery.find()? The code you gave seems not to be jQuery code. The fact that jQuery uses the `$` character, that PHP uses for all its variables, is just a coincidence. They are not related.

Comment: Start with what errors you are getting. It looks like you are trying to mix serverside code with clientside code. The two do not mix.

Comment: I thought it may be better in Jquery. but PHP solution is welcome, i changed also the title

Comment: maybe you need to turn your see to xpath. It can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to parse HTML code using PHP you can use this [library](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

its sample code looks like this

```
 // Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

// Find all images
foreach($html->find('img') as $element)
       echo $element->src . '<br>';

// Find all links
foreach($html->find('a') as $element)
       echo $element->href . '<br>';
```

And if your are fetching data from other sites or file this may be a good idea. I think you don't want to use this method to do manipulation in your front-end html in that case use `jquery`